# Merge new rows from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say two dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'test'], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'baz'], 'c': [2, 1]})

df1
      A  b  c
0   foo  1  3
1   bar  2  4
2  test  3  5

df2
     A  c
0  foo  2
1  baz  1
```

After merging I want:

```
df1
      A  b    c
0   foo  1    3
1   bar  2    4
2  test  3    5
3   baz  NaN  1
```

If `df1['A']` does not contain any thing from `df2['A']`, only that row(s) from `df2` need to be added to `df1`. Ignore other columns when there is a match in col `A`.

I tried `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A'], how='outer')`, but this does not give expected output.

Additionally, for future reference, I also want to know how to get the below output:

```
df1
      A  b    c
0   foo  1    2
1   bar  2    4
2  test  3    5
3   baz  NaN  1
```

See the updated col `c` value from `df2` for `foo`.

Comment: something like `pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('A').first()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `combine_first`

```
out = df1.set_index('A').combine_first(df2.set_index('A')).reset_index()
      A    b  c
0   bar  2.0  4
1   baz  NaN  1
2   foo  1.0  3
3  test  3.0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, you need to fill `c` with values from the other dataframe:

```py
(df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'c': 'c_y'}), on='A', how = 'outer')
    .assign(c = lambda df: df.c.fillna(df.c_y))
    .drop(columns = 'c_y')
)
      A    b    c
0   foo  1.0  3.0
1   bar  2.0  4.0
2  test  3.0  5.0
3   baz  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check if `df1['A']` values are in `df2['A']` which a boolean Series use that in boolean indexing. Then use [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

```
m   = df2['A'].isin(df1['A'])
out = df1.append(df2[~m], ignore_index=True)
print(out)

#       A    b  c
# 0   foo  1.0  3
# 1   bar  2.0  4
# 2  test  3.0  5
# 3   baz  NaN  1
```